# how to get ip address of a Window phone 7 programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, ip

I want to get the IP address of my phone in my app which i am developing for Wp 7.0,
Is there anyway to do that? As there is no support for the same in WP 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple hack for WP7.0

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://whatismyip.org");
       WebClient client = new WebClient();
       client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
       client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       myIP = e.Result;
   }
```

But it's worked, but isn't great way.

For WP 7.5 read [Finding Your Own IP Address On Windows Phone Mango](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2011/08/11/finding-your-own-ip-address-on-windows-phone-mango.aspx)

Hope it's help